# javascript dynamically adding classes without using inline functions

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple example, if a user clicks on element then all the elements above it should have a class and all elements below it should not have any class applied to them.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
p {
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

</style>

<div id="divid">
  <p id="p1">one</p>
  <p id="p2">two</p>
  <p id="p3">three</p>
  <p id="p4">four</p>
</div>
<script>

function myFunction(index) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        paragraphs[i].classList.add('active');
    }
    for (let i = index; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        paragraphs[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
}

var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
console.log(paragraphs);
for(var j=0;j<paragraphs.length; j++) {
    paragraphs[j].addEventListener("click", myFunction(j));
}

</script>
```

When I run this code it is directly setting the class active to first 3 paragraph tags which is not the expected behaviour, and also the click function is not working.

If I replace the javascrip code with inline function, it is working without issues.

```
var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
console.log(paragraphs);
for(var j=0;j<paragraphs.length; j++) {
    paragraphs[j].addEventListener("click", (function(index) {
    return function() {
         for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            paragraphs[i].classList.add('active');
        }
        for (let i = index; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            paragraphs[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
  })(j));
}
```

Can you please help me what is the issue with my code if I place it as external function?

Comment: `with inline function`  What do you mean? The second snippet doesn't look like an inline function, it looks like a standard script, which there's nothing wrong with. It *is* in the Javascript and not the HTML, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function inside of an anonymous function:

```js
function myFunction(index) {
  for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].classList.add('active');
  }
  for (let i = index; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
}

var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

for(let j=0;j<paragraphs.length; j++) {
  paragraphs[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
    myFunction(j);
  });
}
```

```css
p {
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="divid">
  <p id="p1">one</p>
  <p id="p2">two</p>
  <p id="p3">three</p>
  <p id="p4">four</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`myFunction(j)` in addEventListener will immediately execute the function. Replace it with only `myFunction`. The `myFunction` will get the `event` object. From event object you can get the target which will be useful to get the index of the child element.

You can adjust the iteration over `m` value to add or remove class from desired elements

```js
function myFunction(index) {
  // this will first create an array of all the child elmenets
  // then the indexOf will get the index of the child which was clicked
  let m = Array.from(index.target.parentNode.children).indexOf(index.target);
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].classList.add('active');
  }
  for (let i = m + 1; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
}

var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

for (var j = 0; j < paragraphs.length; j++) {
  paragraphs[j].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```

```css
p {
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="divid">
  <p id="p1">one</p>
  <p id="p2">two</p>
  <p id="p3">three</p>
  <p id="p4">four</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting the reason you're encountering an issue is because typically external files are loaded *before* all of your DOM elements get a chance to load. Whenever you have an inline function, typically you define it *after* your DOM elements so your elements have loaded which is why you're able to select them and add event listeners.

Try wrapping your logic in this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   // Place your code here.
});
```

Or if you use jQuery, use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Place your code here.
});
```

This'll allow your DOM elements to load before you attempt to use them in your code making them accessible in separate js files.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)** by having the parent div listen for the click event for all of its descendant nodes. Now any `<p>` clicked would be the **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** and the parent div is **[`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)**. Those 2 Event properties will reliably reference the nodes without the need for ids, classes, attributes or tagNames.

As an external file place the `<script>` tag before the closing `</body>` tag. It works 99.9% of the time.

## [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/5r9kqWazbOH25MfORwKJ/)

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

```js
// Reference the parent node
var mom = document.querySelector('div');

/* Collect all of mom's paragraphs into a nodeList then turn it into an array.
 */
var kids = Array.from(mom.querySelectorAll('p'));

/* Event Delegation
|| Register the click event to mom
|| Now any click to a kid (e.target) will propagate to mom (e.currentTarget). 
|| That's only one event listener for any number of descendant nodes.
*/
mom.addEventListener('click', olderBros);


function olderBros(e) {

  // Remove .active from all of the kids
  kids.forEach(function(k) {
    k.className = "";
  });

  // Make sure that the clicked node is NOT mom 
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    // Reference the clicked node...
    var tgt = e.target;

    // Assign the clicked node .active class
    // Remove this line if you don't want clicked node .active
    tgt.className = "active";

    var i, j = kids.legnth;
    // Add .active to all older/previous <p>/Element Bros/Sibling
    for (i = 0; tgt = tgt.previousElementSibling; i++) {
      kids[i].classList.add('active');
    }

    // Remove .active to all younger/next <p>/Element Bros/Sibling
    for (let k = (i + 1); k < (j - i); k++) {
      kids[k].classList.remove('active');
    }

  } else {
    return false;
  }
  // Stop event bubbling
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p {
      background-color: skyblue;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .active {
      color: red;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
    <p>four</p>
    <p>five</p>
    <p>six</p>
    <p>seven</p>
    <p>eight</p>
    <p>nine</p>
    <p>ten</p>
    <p>eleven</p>
    <p>twelve</p>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```